# Firebase Functions response returns null

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, function, firebase

tried get list of objects from s3(actually from wasabi) but in react always returns null

function code:
(using node 8)

```
exports.fetchWasabi = functions.https.onCall(() => {

  const params = 
  {
        Bucket: 'balde1-webcars',
  };

  s3.listObjectsV2(params, function(err, result) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log(result)
            return result
        } else {
            console.log(err); 
            return err
        }
  });


});
```

react code:

```
componentDidMount(){
    var Wasabi = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('fetchWasabi');
    Wasabi().then(function(result) {
        var res = result.data;
        console.log(res)
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
}
```

when i check the log for the function i can see the result but it never reaches my browser apparently

Comment: Why are you missing your semicolons friend

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything so you should add one more return like :

```
return s3.listObjectsV2(params, function(err, result) { ...
```